# Thermodynamics derivatives: Does $(\partial A/\partial B) = (\partial B/\partial A)^{-1}$?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, free-energy

If I need to find, for instance:
$$\mathcal{T} := \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V, N}$$
knowing:
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_{V, N} = \frac{1}{T}$$
Can I say that $\mathcal{T} = (1/T)^{-1} = T$ ? In general terms, let $A$ and $B$ are two thermodynamics values, is it true that
$(\partial A/\partial B) = (\partial B/\partial A)^{-1}$ ?

Comment: The question is better suited for Math.SE, where it [already exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1744014).

Comment: are thermodynamics variables "usually" strictly monotome ?

Comment: There are singularities like near 0 K or the liquid critical point, where some partial derivatives converge to 0 or $\pm \infty$

Comment: ok, and between those singularities ?

Comment: Usually monotonous , but there are exceptions, like local minima for water heat capacity near 36 °C, or for molar volume near 4 °C. Or maxima of electric conductivity of concentrated electrolytes.

Comment: Additionally, such partial derivatives may be undefined at some points, typically at phase changes.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll avoid using this formula then

Comment: @andselisk  This question is about thermodynamics, and belongs here.  The Math.SE answer says it's not generally the case that, for a function of more than one variable (e.g., z(x,y)), that (∂z/∂x)_y = 1/(∂x/∂z)_y.  However, in thermodynamics, we're generally dealing with equilibrium systems, which means we are operating under the constraint that dz = 0. And under that constraint, we can derive the cyclic rule and the relationship that (∂z/∂x)_y = 1/(∂x/∂z)_y.  So yes, this formula should be used (and often needs to be used) in thermodynamic derivations.  Just watch out for singularities.

Comment: As a mathematics student- although dB/dA is not always equal to (dA/dB)^(-1), it IS equal for "nice" functions A, B. Most functions appearing in applied mathematics are "nice", so in your case dB/dA can be considered to be equal to (dA/dB)^(-1).